# Ajax isn't updating properly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have this wierd error where I have a custom control called "Header",
inside it I have another custom control called "Body",
in the body control, I've put telerik's DateTimePicker.

Problem is that when I try from the "Header" extracting the date (from the server side), I get only the initialized date.
Worth to mention that I've put Header + Body controls in an AjaxManager,
And in the Body control, I've put the DateTimePicker in an AjaxManager with itself.

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use ajax manager proxies and a single manager on the main page as told here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/usercontrol/defaultcs.aspx. Or, alternatively, use a single manager and set the ajax settings programatically.